# Резиновый блок и изображение

Tags: jquery, изображения, css, javascript

Моя страница резиновая и состоит из 3х столбцов 15%, 70% и 15%.
СSS третьего столбца:

```
width: 15%;
padding: 5px;
background-color: #F1F1F1;
// здесь сама суть
background-image: url('/css/images/logo.png');
background-position: bottom;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-size: 100% auto;
// а здесь она заканчивается
float: right;
border-left: black solid 1px;
display: block;
height: 100%;
box-sizing: border-box;
overflow-x: hidden;
overflow-y: auto;
word-wrap: break-word;
margin: 0;
```

Как видите на фоне стоит изображение, которое расположено снизу и растягивается по ширине столбца, а высота устанавливается автоматом.

Но когда я добавляю в тот блок текст (а он здесь необходим), он перекрывает изображение
[Скрин](http://cs411824.userapi.com/v411824599/859/IYBqbq9jI7U.jpg) (сюда залить не смог)

Мне нужно решить эту проблему.
Сложность как раз в том, что страница и столбец резиновые.

Внутри этого блока с фоном есть еще один блок в котором и находится текст. Этот блок и должен быть с высотой раной пустому пространству.

Желательно реализовать это с помощью только CSS, но если это не возможно (хотя я так не думаю), то можно воспользоваться JS и jQuery

Размер самого изображения 500*438

PS Уже второй день ломаю голову, и буду очень благодарен, если поможете

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Оставьте резиновой только центральную колонку. Резина в сайдбарах совершенно ни к чему.

Поскольку в таком случае вы будете точно знать ширину колонки, будет легче разобраться и с высотой блока с текстом, используя, к примеру, css-свойство [display](http://htmlbook.ru/css/display): посмотреть в сторону **table-cell** и **table-row**.

Comment: Я реализовал єто с помощью JS.
Так я понял слишком муторно будет.
Спасибо за ответі

Answer (score 0):

Вы внутреннему блоку сделайте:

```
#block{
   position: absolute;
   bottom: 500px;
   height: auto;
   width: 100%;   
}
```

Comment: дак высота логотипа неизвестна, и растянуться колонка может так, что изображение налезет на текст все равно...

Comment: Да да да.
В принципе я решил проблему с помощью jquery, но честно говоря, мне это не нравится

Comment: @Yura Ivanov, вам же написано: 

>Размер самого изображения 500*438

Comment: @Rules, это размер оригинала, который масштабируется в зависимости от ширины резиновой колонки. Там может быть высота и 30px  и 1000px. Читайте внимательнее.

Comment: Тогда без JS никак ):